# Adding a new member (even a whole namespace) to an already existing namespace alias

Tags: c++, namespaces, alias

Let `library` be a namespace from an external source (e.g. shared library). Let `global` be a global namespace for a project that uses that external source.

By using

```
namepace global
{
    namespace external = library;
}
```

the `library` namespace can now be used by accessing `global::external`. Now imaging `other_library` (with no conflicts with `library`) being a namespace from a second external source. Is it possible to add `other_library` to the alias `external` so that functionality from both external sources can be access via `global::external`?

Reason: provide a unified access to different resources by hiding underlying namespaces and grouping those into a different, custom API-friendly way.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Inline_namespaces

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
namespace global
{
    namespace external{
        using namespace library;
        using namespace other_library;
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I am not 100% sure that unpacking namespaces with `using` is equivalent to namespace aliases especially w.r.t very dark corners of function overloading and ADL.

Comment: it also might not have retroactive power, i.e. won't act on something included after. I used that trick though, to incorporate either boost or std classes, whichever headers were included, into single custom namespace